# Javascript variable comes up in console but is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

my template on https://gambur.ch has no callback function i can call to get the inventory. it adds an URLSeacrchParam with the variant ID to the URL.

I manage to catch that variant id and show it in console (see: https://gambur.ch/collections/reithosen/products/reithose-karen-black-onyx on click on options) i have to use a timeout as it takes a few millisecond until the Param is updatet...

but then I can't get the second part of the script working as may currentVariant Variable shows "undefined"

Goal is to unhide the inventory of the given variant...

```
$(".option-value-input").click(
function() {
    console.log("clicked...reading stock information");

    setTimeout(
        function() {
          var currentVariant = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          console.log(currentVariant.get('variant'));
        },
        500);

      $(".variantStock").each(function(){
    var variantsIDs = $(this).data("id");
  if(currentVariant === variantsIDs ){
    $(this).removeClass("is-hidden");
  }else{
    $(this).addClass("is-hidden");
  }
});
```

});

Comment: Also check this condition `currentVariant === variantsIDs` comparing a string to URLSearchParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a classic asynchronous coding mistake. Your code executes before the variable gets assign since it does not wait for the 500 milliseconds.

```
$(".option-value-input").click(
function() {
    console.log("clicked...reading stock information");

    setTimeout(
        function() {
          var currentVariant = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          console.log(currentVariant.get('variant'));
          $(".variantStock").each(function(){
            var variantsIDs = $(this).data("id");
            if(currentVariant === variantsIDs ){
              $(this).removeClass("is-hidden");
            }else{
              $(this).addClass("is-hidden");
            }
          });
        },
        500); 
});
```

I added the full code in the setTimeout for it to run when you expect it to run.